# Android exclamation mark error

Tags: android, android-appcompat

A moment ago I updated Java to 8.025 (and auto removed the old one) so suddenly Eclipse won´t start. Therefore I reinstalled eclipse with the Andriod SDK and everything but now no project works anymore working from the same workspace. Creating a new project gives an exclamation mark on the project folder, the rest of the projects have one (!?) class that gives an error. I´m fairly sure that this has something to do with the appcompat thing that automatically gets installed but that´s just a guess. 
Cleaning all projects gives back this error for a bunch of themes it seems:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
```

Sorry for not being anymore precise but I have no clue of what is going on. If someone could explain this appcompat thing, what it does, and why it is needed as well (as if you´re explaining it to a child), and give a guess of what might be wrong that would be awesome.

Also, even the appcompat gives an error. Seems strange as it gets installed automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v7 appcompat library gets added when you create a new project in Eclipse if the min SDK is set lower than API 14. v7 appcompat library adds support for the Action Bar user interface design pattern. This library includes support for material design user interface implementations. This library is located in the /extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/ directory after you download the Android Support Libraries. Source: [Android Support Library Features](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html).
This library depends on the v4 Support Library. Make sure you include the v4 Support Library. Also make sure that the projects that include v7 appcompat library have same version of v4 Support Library as well.

In regards to the resource error and themes errors, make sure that the App theme in styles.xml in values-v11 values-v14 etc. folders in the projects that include v7 appcompat library are updated to the latest appcompat themes.

Since appcompat library project is giving error, it may be because the appcompat project is older version (Preview L) and should be updated to (v21 Android 5.0). I suggest deleting the library project and adding it again following these steps in Eclipse:

1. Select File > Import.
2. Select Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
3. Browse to the SDK installation directory and then to the Support
   Library folder. For example, if you are adding the appcompat
           project, browse to /extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/.
4. Click Finish to import the project. For the v7 appcompat project,
   you should now see a new project titled
           android-support-v7-appcompat.
5. In the new library project, expand the libs/ folder, right-click
   each .jar file and select Build Path > Add to Build
           Path. For example, when creating the the v7 appcompat project, add
           both the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
           files to the build path.
6. Right-click the library project folder and select Build Path >
   Configure Build Path.
7. In the Order and Export tab, check the .jar files you just added to
   the build path, so they are available to projects that
           depend on this library project. For example, the appcompat project
           requires you to export both the android-support-v4.jar and
           android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files.
8. Uncheck Android Dependencies.
9. Click OK to complete the changes.

Source: [Android Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res)

Comment: @user2069136 did you get the projects to work? Was my reply helpful?

Comment: Yes, everything is up and running now. Thanks again! Forgot to check it as answered and sorry I have to little rep to vote it up :(